# Unity 5.2 - Animate Sprite

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I am having difficulty animating a sprite in Unity.
I want the Sprites sprite(image) to change in a looping animation.
So far I have created a new animation and added the sprites to the animation timeline as shown in the image below.
[image]
As you can see above, I am also animating the colour of the sprite.
The GameObject looks like this:
[image]
When the scene is run, the colour component animates as expected, however the sprite does not change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you would not get any answer then let me know, I will give you a simple script to change sprites :)

Comment: Check this [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113345/is-there-any-other-way-to-animate-2d-spritesheet-without-animator-component-in-u) if problem exists.

Comment: @HamzaHasan Thanks for the link, trying to get this working with the built in animator though.

Comment: It is explicitly without animator

Comment: it is for the side objects,

Answer (score 0):

Try manually change colour. If you don't see effect, check your shader in material. Maybe your shader haven't property Colour. You can too try change default shader.